# JAVA generate Soap web service XML and XSD

Tags: java, xml, soap, jboss, xsd-validation

I'm new on SOAP web services, I'm using java, netbeans and jboss to accomplish it. I have a simple web service:

```
@WebSerice
public class HelloSoap() {
   public String sayHello(String name) {
      return "Hello "+name;
   }
}
```

when I deploy and run the application it generates XML file correctly:

> http://host/service/HelloSoap?wsdl

but it does not have schemaLocations, the XSD file and if I go to

> http://host/service/HelloSoap?xsd=1

It says:
`<soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Could not find xsd 1</faultstring>
 </soap:Fault>`

How would be the correct way to generate XML file with XSD included. Did I miss some code or configuration. 
I'm kinda confused, thank you for help.

Comment: What XSD do you want to load? Because that is, what you have to set as the parameter value: ``?xsd=myscheme.xsd``

Comment: Then, do I have to create manually XSD schema?  is it not generated?

Comment: There is normally no extra schema when generating the WSDL from code. A client is generated directly from the WSDL with the appropriate tools. [Please read about it.](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html)

Comment: Then, what would be the correct way to generate XSD file?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Let me be clear: There is no XSD file. If you want to create an XML request you use a tool like SOAP-UI which does that directly from the WSDL.